# Assembly language with C or C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, assembly

I should write the program in Assembly and C or C++ languages.
The main module in C has the task to take the data from the user and display the results.

There are 2 procedures in the assembly module.

The first one must take the array of real numbers from the main module, and return the average of the elements of the array.

The second one must take the array of character and one a single character and return to the main module sum of these characters in the array.

For example:

```
array:     'Kangaroo'
character: 'o'
Return 2.
```

I have been write this, but it does not work. I do not know what is wrong...

In the C++ code i have:

```
extern "C" float average(float* tab, int G);
extern "C" int  search(int n, char a, char* arr);
```

And here all is ok.

But here it is my assembly code:

```
.386
.model SMALL,c
PUBLIC search
PUBLIC average
.stack          400h

.data

    _Result  DW  ?
     one dd 1.0

.code

search PROC

    push    bp        
    mov     bp, sp

    mov dx, 0           
    mov al, [bp+6]    
    mov cx,0           
    jmp compare

    compare:       
        cmp al, [bp+12]
        je increment
        jmp continue

    increment:
        inc cx         
        jmp continue
    continue:
        add bp, 1       
        inc dx       
        cmp dx, 100         
        jne compare  
        jmp end

   end:

    mov _Result, cx      
    mov ax, _Result      
    pop bp              
    ret 


search ENDP

average PROC

    push ebp
    mov esp,ebp

    push esi

    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    mov esi, [ebp+8] 

    finit

    fldz 

    denominator:
    fld dword PTR one

    fld    dword PTR [esi]    

    fdivp st(1), st(0)   

    faddp st(1),st(0)

    add esi,4
    loop denominator

    pop esi
    pop ebp
    ret 

average ENDP

END
```

I am using the DosBox with BorlandC compiler.
In the "Average" i always have the result as 0 or error.
In the "Search" i have the wrong answer.

Please, help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `search` function, you are comparing `al` to `[bp+12]`. That only works on the first character. When you add to bp, you are messing up your stack frame. `[bp+12]` is your char*. You need to move `[bp+12]` to a register and use that register as your `char*`. Increment that register each time through the loop, rather than incrementing `bp`. `bp` needs to stay the same until you exit your function.

Also, `a` is at `bp+8`, not `bp+6`. You might need to check your compiler settings to find out whether `arr` is actually at `bp+12` or `bp+10`. It will depend on whether the compiler pushes the char as 2 bytes or 4.

Also, you are looping 100 times through your array unconditionally. Presumably `n` is your array size, so move that to `cx` and use `cx` as your loop counter.

In your `sum` function, `tab` is at `bp+4` and `G` is at `bp+8`. Note that you're getting them (`ecx` and `esi`) from the wrong offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
_Sum:
        push    ebp             ; create stack frame
        mov     ebp, esp
        mov     eax, [ebp+8]    ; grab the first argument
        mov     ecx, [ebp+12]   ; grab the second argument
        add     eax, ecx        ; sum the arguments
        pop     ebp             ; restore the base pointer
        ret
```

you need to set up stack at the beginning and then take the arguments from stack appropriately. 
I'm quite convinced, that `[bp+6]`  in your code may lead to trouble, because there is no data type that would fit this offset. 
More on mixing C and assembly can be read here: http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/c-prog-mixing.html

Comment: One might ask what the point in the saving and restoring of the stack frame is. You're not using the stack at all.

Comment: You are when you're interacting with C.

Comment: How so? Are you sure?

Comment: The C calling convention requires all argument to be passed via stack. Probably due to lack of registers on x86 processors (unlike modern RISC processors)

Comment: That doesn't mean that you *must* say `push ebp`. You could just skip the prologue and epilogue and use `esp` in place of `ebp`.

Comment: I guess you're right. Although, it's probably safer this way.